# Bibliography style paragraphs wrong behavior

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{afterpage}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
 }

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
\date{\today}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{cp{5in}c}
    &\everypar{\hangindent1em \hangafter1} 

    Aas, T. (2013). Free public transport in Tallinn - financial, enviromental and social aspects. Presentation on Union of th Baltic Cities Joint Seminar on Sustainable Transport Solutions. Tallinn, Estonia. Retrieved from http://www.tallinn.ee/eng/tasutauhistransport/UBC-Joint-Seminar-on-Sustainable-Transport-solutions

    Cats, O., Reimal, T., & Susilo, Y. (2014). Public Transport Pricing Policy - Empirical Evidence from a Fare-Free Scheme in Tallin, Estonia. Transportation Research Record, Journal of the Transporation Research Board.

    Galey Derek. (2014). License to Ride: Free Public Transportation for Residents of Tallin. A Journal of the UCLA Department of Urban Planning.
    Hamilton, C. (2012). Decisive factors for the acceptability of congestion pricing. Working paper, Stockholm Center for Transport Studies.


    &
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I want to have something in this style ( i mean first line smaller indent  than the subsequent one):
[image]

But result of my code is:[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: wouldn't it be more natural (and better as it allows page breaks) to use list markup rather than a table and the tex primitive \hangafter ?

Comment: your example has mismatched `&` and generates an error `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 
                             
l.41     &`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i am not sure whether i know how to change it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you get a TeX error  you should look at the log file, not the pdf output. TeX does not attempt to make sensible typeset result as it recovers from an error.

```
 Cats, O., Reimal, T., & Susilo,
```

needs to be

```
 Cats, O., Reimal, T., \& Susilo,
```

the error message is quite explicit about the extra `&`

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.41     &
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you absolutely want to make your bibliography by hand (which is not recommended, as it will probably not meet the standards), it's easier to use a `description` environment, which can break across pages, and can be customised with the `enumitem`  package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black
}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\newpage}
\date{\today}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{cp{5in}c}
    & \everypar{\hangindent4em \hangafter1}
  Aas, T. (2013). Free public transport in Tallinn - financial, environmental and social aspects. Presentation on Union of the Baltic Cities Joint Seminar on Sustainable Transport Solutions. Tallinn, Estonia. Retrieved from \url{http://www.tallinn.ee/eng/tasutauhistransport/UBC-Joint-Seminar-on-Sustainable-Transport-solutions}

  Cats, O., Reimal, T., \& Susilo, Y. (2014). Public Transport Pricing Policy - Empirical Evidence from a Fare-Free Scheme in Tallin, Estonia. Transportation Research Record, Journal of the Transportation Research Board.

  Galey Derek. (2014). License to Ride: Free Public Transportation for Residents of Tallinn. A Journal of the UCLA Department of Urban Planning.
  Hamilton, C. (2012). Decisive factors for the acceptability of congestion pricing. Working paper, Stockholm Center for Transport Studies.
\end{tabular}
\vskip0.5cm
\begin{description}[leftmargin=4em, rightmargin=6em]
  \item Aas, T. (2013). Free public transport in Tallinn - financial, environmental and social aspects. Presentation on Union of the Baltic Cities Joint Seminar on Sustainable Transport Solutions. Tallinn, Estonia. Retrieved from \url{http://www.tallinn.ee/eng/tasutauhistransport/UBC-Joint-Seminar-on-Sustainable-Transport-solutions}

  \item Cats, O., Reimal, T., \& Susilo, Y. (2014). Public Transport Pricing Policy - Empirical Evidence from a Fare-Free Scheme in Tallin, Estonia. Transportation Research Record, Journal of the Transportation Research Board.

  \item Galey Derek. (2014). License to Ride: Free Public Transportation for Residents of Tallinn. A Journal of the UCLA Department of Urban Planning.
  Hamilton, C. (2012). Decisive factors for the acceptability of congestion pricing. Working paper, Stockholm Center for Transport Studies.

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No bibliography entries were just as an example ;) , i did not want to disclose the original text i have. Still good to know what you wrote as this helps as well with what i want to have.